# How to disable link on “Created By” column vale of a list item in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I saw this answer by Shoban:

- Go to List - > Settings -> List Settings
- Under "Columns"
- Click "Created by" to open column settings
- Under "Additional Column Settings" Change Show Filed to "Name".
- Repeat the above steps for 'Modified by"

» This will just Show the Name and will not have the link.

This does not work in Sharpoint 2010 I still get a link when Show Feild is set "Name". 
Anyone have a solution for SharePoint 2010?

Comment: I dont have acces to SP2010 now. I will go back home and reply if no one replies. Bokmarked! :-)

Comment: Would you mind sharing the link to "this answer by Shoban"?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution using JQuery.

Unfortunately in Sharepoint 2010 when a View has collapsed groups, this script will not work. The only way around this that I could find is to have them 'expanded' by default.

Ensure that your page has a reference to a modern version of JQuery, and add the following to your View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Remove "Contact" links
    $('a[href*="userdisp.aspx"]:visible=false').each(function(index) {
        var link = $(this);
        $(this).after("<span>" + link.text() + "</span>");
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did a 2010 site choosing Name from the show field choices.  Worked like a charm for 2010 for me.  Next stop 2013

Answer (score -1):

The above method works fine for SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Sorry, but wrong. When you set the *Show Field* to "Name" (or e.g. "ID" for that matter), you still get a link for the field. This is the same for lists and document libraries. This makes sense because the link is not defined in the "Show field" setting, but in the XSLT defining the list view. The show field simply is about the "display" of the link - i.e. it changes `<a href="...">show field</a>`, but the link stays.

Comment: Have you tested it? I posted my answer after testing.

Comment: I have tested in SP foundation and SP Server 2010 and the result is a moontear describes, no matter what field I choose the list shows "Created By" as a hyperlink to the User Info page. Can you provide some guidence on modifying the XSLT to solve this issue?

Comment: Thats weird. I have tested in SP2010 enterprise edition and when I select name it does not show the link.